# Number rank-k 0-1 matrices (characteristic 0)

Tags: co.combinatorics, pr.probability, matrices

What is the number of $n\times n$ 0/1-matrices with rank $k$?
(The rank is taken over the rationals.)

Answer (score 5):

This sequence is [OEIS A064230 Triangle T(n,k) = number of rational (0,1) matrices of rank k (n >= 0, 0 <= k <= n)](https://oeis.org/A064230)

According to comments rows add to $2^{n^2}$.

There are some references and pari/gp code.

Comment: I think I can understand that the rows add up to $2^{n^2}$ without checking the numbers (every matrix has a rank).

Comment: On the other hand the other comment "... that almost all such matrices are invertible" seems out of place, since the cited article mentions matrices with entries $\pm1$ in its title. And indeed it appears that corank $1$ is more frequent than corank $0$, at least for the displayed numbers.

Comment: $\pm 1$ matrices and $(0,1)$ matrices are equivalent here.  When counting $\pm 1$ matrices, we can assume without loss of generality that the first row and column are all $-1$.  After subtracting the first row from each other row, the lower right $(n-1) \times (n-1)$ block has entries uniform and independent on $\{0,2\}$.  So the probability an $n \times n$ $\pm 1$ matrix has corank $k$ is the same as that an $(n-1) \times (n-1)$ $(0,1)$ matrix has corank $k$.