# Counting 0-1 $n\times n$ matrices with a given rank r

Tags: co.combinatorics, linear-algebra, matrices

What is the number $N$ of $n \times n$ $0$-$1$ matrices with rank $k$?

I read this sequence is 
"OEIS A064230 Triangle $T(n,k)$ = number of rational (0,1) matrices of rank $k$ ($n\ge 0$, $0\le k\le n$)".

I am interested in approximation results, i.e. finding upper and/or lower bound for $N$ when $k=\Theta(f(n))$ for some function $f$.

Thank you!
PS: I would like to emphasize that, for this "counting problem" context, I am asking only for (even rough) estimates.

Comment: The Zivkovic reference there is the latest I know.  Considering the large number of such matrices, I suspect you will not see an exact and useful enumeration any time soon.  I suspect even approximations will be very rough. Gerhard "Doesn't Know The Rank Asymptotics" Paseman, 2017.10.10.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Number rank-k 0-1 matrices (characteristic 0)](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/143488/number-rank-k-0-1-matrices-characteristic-0)

Comment: @777, this question asks for estimates, that one doesn't. Not quite a duplicate, I think.

Comment: @GerryMyerson https://mathoverflow.net/questions/195326/enumerating-matrices-function-of-ranks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Enumerating matrices function of ranks](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/195326/enumerating-matrices-function-of-ranks)

Comment: I am asking here, for the first time, about (even quite rough) estimates. Thanks

Comment: Then consider the problem over the two element field, and use that and published values as a guide. Again, follow up the references in the OEIS.  Gerhard "Roughness Is Roughly Characteristic Invariant" Paseman, 2017.10.11.